# Mysql return 0 when i use count

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have this table:

Notifications

```
+-------+--------+--------+
| id    |category| notify |
+-------+--------+--------+
|     1 |products|     yes|
|     2 |web     |     no |
|     3 |clients |     yes|
|     4 |clients |     yes|
+-------+--------+--------+
```

I need this result:

```
Category | Count |
products |      1|
web      |      0|
clients  |      2|
```

I tried

```
SELECT count(*), category
FROM Notifications
WHERE notify = "yes"
GROUP BY category
```

but I get

```
Category | Count |
products |      1|
 clients |      2|
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method to get *all* categories in `Notifications` is to use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT n.category, sum(n.notify = 'no')
FROM Notifications n
GROUP BY n.category;
```

If you have a separate table of categories, then you can get *all* categories (even those without notifications) using `left join`:

```
select c.category, count(n.category)
from categories c left join
     notifications n
     on c.category = n.category and n.notify = 'no'
group by c.category;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) AS no_category FROM Notifications 
WHERE notify="no" GROUP BY category;
```

With this the count value will be stored inside no_category. Using PHP, you can

```
echo $row["no_category"];
```

And on the MySQL console, the query will generate a table in the form

### no_category

1

Answer (score 0):

And, you can also use the ubiquitous `case` statement to perform conditional aggregation.

```
Select category, 
  Sum(case when Notify = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) count, 
FROM Notifications
GROUP BY category
```